# What would be considered infringement on patent US 8327659 B2

Tags: prior-art, patent-infringement, us8327659

A patent on a "cooler" is covering a wider spectrum of products. There are numerous cooler companies. Would they be committing infringement on this patent just by making a cooler? Or perhaps the difference comes in when the different companies make coolers a different way or feature different designs on the cooler. Would it be considered safe to use several patented materials to make a new cooler that is not on the market and patent and/or sell such a item?

[US 8327659 B2](http://www.google.com/patents/US8327659)

> **Claim 1:**
>   
>   An **insulated cooler** comprising:
>
> a **main cooler body having multiple side walls and a bottom wall** forming a product container with a top opening;
>
> a lid constructed and arranged for selectively covering the top opening;
>
> at least two of said multiple side walls being adjacent to each other, and each of said adjacent side walls having a design zone thereon; and
>
> a **design panel system** having an inner side design portion overlaying the side wall design zone and an outer side portion comprising **a protective shielding cover** for the inner side design portion.

Answer (score 1):

Although what this patent claims may not be spectacularly clever, it only covers specific coolers with "display panels" as it defines them. Looking just at claim 1, it needs to be a cooler and it needs to have a display panel on one inner sidewall with a protective shielding cover. If I understand the question, making it from "patented materials" doesn't affect the situation one way or the other.

They are not claiming specific designs that might be in the design panel system. Please edit the question or add a comment if I have misunderstood the question.